# Screen sharing in Unity3D using Agora.io

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io

I'm trying to screen share my app display built from Unity to a website.

However, I've notice agora using
`externalVideoFrame.format = ExternalVideoFrame.VIDEO_PIXEL_FORMAT.VIDEO_PIXEL_BGRA;`

In unity, `Texture2D.ReadPixels` only support RGB.
So when I did this, the receiving end will have Red & Blue swapped.

Is there any way to get BGR in Unity? or Agora have RGB support?
I tried to invert the byte[] before sending over agora, but the performance is very bad.. at 1 fps best.

Answer (score 2):

> In unity, Texture2D.ReadPixels only support RGB.

Actually, that's not true.  ReadPixels reads for the format that was set by Texture2D object instantiation.  In [the Unity scripting example](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.ReadPixels.html) you see "TextureFormat.RGB24".  Instead of that, you should use TextureFormat.BGRA32, which will match what the Agora API requires.

Comment: I did try to change the Texture2D format but still not valid in Unity.. It give errors when read pixels in BGR.

You may refer to [Jake Priddy](https://medium.com/@jake_agora.io/how-to-broadcast-your-screen-with-unity3d-and-agora-io-10006b8a4aa7) for code, and [Unity Doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.ReadPixels.html) for ReadPixel.
_This function works on RGBA32, ARGB32 and RGB24 texture formats_